# How does midicps work in overtone?

Tags: clojure, overtone

I'm trying to add in some microtonal functionality to overtone, but I'm having issues when it comes to dealing with the function midicps, which seems to be a requirement for dealing with midi input.

This is what I want:

```
(definst instrument [note 64 amp 0.5 gate 1]
  (* amp (lpf (lf-tri (foo note) ) 1100)
  (env-gen (adsr 0.1 0.2 2 2 0.3) gate :action FREE)))
```

foo is a function that takes a midi value and maps it to a value in hz (sort of like midicps), however, the above code doesn't run correctly.

For the sake of testing, I've defined foo as:

```
(defn foo [x] (if (= 64 x) 880 440))
```

Thus, `(instrument 64)` should play a note an octave higher than any other foo, but it doesn't.

I believe what is happening is that when I run `(instrument x)`, it passes something else (a midi event?) to foo instead of the integer itself.

Any time I try running `midi->hz` over `midicps`, I get the error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: overtone.sc.machinery.ugen.sc_ugen.SCUGen 
cannot be cast to java.lang.Number, compiling:(form-init7628662755818333410.clj:1:1)
```

Calling midi->hz on note without midicps yields the same error.

How do I convert this ugen (or midi event) to an integer representing the midi note?

Note: I'm using `midi-poly-player` to add the midi handler for my instrument. I can get my pitch mapping function to work if I just make a regular note-on event handler, but I would much rather use `midi-poly-player` so I don't have to re-implement all of it's functionality.

Comment: Asking this kind of question on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/overtone would probably get quicker answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing scsynth ugens and Clojure code when you call the foo function like this.  Inside the definst, it is a macro taking that Clojure code and converting it to supercollider synthesizer code.  I don't actually understand why the code behaves like it does, but I think I can show you how to make it do what you want.  Just keep the code within the definst macro.

Here is the midi->hz function in Clojure.  midicps does this as a ugen in supercollider for you:

```
(defn midi->hz
  "Convert a midi note number to a frequency in hz."
  [note]
  (* 440.0 (java.lang.Math/pow 2.0 (/ (- note 69.0) 12.0))))
```

You can just inline that note->frequency conversion in your definst:

```
(definst instrument2 [note 64 amp 0.5 gate 1]
  (let [freq (* 440.0 (pow 2.0 (/ (- note 69.0) 12.0)))]
    (* amp (lpf (lf-tri freq) 1100)
       (env-gen (adsr 0.1 0.2 2 2 0.3) gate :action FREE))))
```

and listen to the standard 12 notes per scale output like:

```
(def x (instrument2 69))
(ctl x :gate 0)
(def x (instrument2 70))
(ctl x :gate 0)
(def x (instrument2 71))
(ctl x :gate 0)
```

to adjust for more tones-per-octave, for example, this gives 24...

```
(definst instrument3 [note 64 amp 0.5 gate 1]
  (let [freq (* 440.0 (pow 2.0 (/ (- note 69.0) 24.0)))]
    (* amp (lpf (lf-tri freq) 1100)
       (env-gen (adsr 0.1 0.2 2 2 0.3) gate :action FREE))))

(def x (instrument3 69))
(ctl x :gate 0)
(def x (instrument3 70))
(ctl x :gate 0)
(def x (instrument3 71))
(ctl x :gate 0)
```

I hear a series of smaller steps. I hope you do, too.

Cheers,

Roger